# How to keep config after reinstall ipk on OpenWrt

Tags: openwrt

In makefile, I use `INSTALL_DATA` to copy config file to `/etc/config`. And config file will be changed during running.

I found that, after re-install application, the config file will restore to default one packed in ipk.

I want to know how to keep config file after re-install. Anyone can help me?

Makefile:

```
define Package/zm_control/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/etc/config
    $(INSTALL_DATA) ./config/$(PKG_NAME).json $(1)/etc/config/$(PKG_NAME).json
endef
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Package/zm_control/install` target gets executed during package building process, i.e. on your host machine, not on the OpenWrt device. It copies the config file to staging dir that will be embedded into the firmware image file and the `.ipk` file.

The configs in `/etc/config/` folder are preserved automatically when you execute `sysupgrade` without `-n` flag. So, if you re-flash the device with a newly generated image, your config will not be lost.

However, if you want to install a new version of your package using `opkg install` command, you need to define your custom `preinst` and `postinst` targets in the Makefile. Like this:

```
define Package/$(PKG_NAME)/preinst
#!/bin/sh
# check if we are on real system
if [ -z "$${IPKG_INSTROOT}" ]; then
        #Backup config file
        cp /etc/config/$(PKG_NAME).json /tmp/$(PKG_NAME).json.bak
fi
exit 0
endef

define Package/$(PKG_NAME)/postinst
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$${IPKG_INSTROOT}" ]; then
        #Restore config file
        mv /tmp/$(PKG_NAME).json.bak /etc/config/$(PKG_NAME).json
fi
exit 0
endef
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's a simpler solution, just add the config files used by your package to a "conffiles" section in your Makefile:

```
define Package/zm_control/conffiles
/etc/config/config_file1
/etc/config/config_file2
# ecc...
endef
```

Eg: [openwisp-config Makefile](https://github.com/openwisp/openwisp-config/blob/40d20c13c4fa2231fbd7490e3c932fa173b52893/openwisp-config/Makefile#L35-L37)